# AngularJS set form value from controller with ngMessages

Tags: angularjs, forms, ng-messages

I try to use forms with angular 1.5.9 but can't figure out a way to make it work for the following requirements:

1. Access form data from the controller (bound with `controllerAs`)
2. Don't use the `$scope` to bind the form
3. Be able to set default values from the controller
4. Be able to change values from the controller
5. Be able to access data from the controller
6. Having validation working with ngMessages

I've made a commented jsbin to illustrate the problem and what I've tried, you can find it here : http://jsbin.com/guzejelula/edit?html,js,output.

Every requirements up here is satisfied in the jsbin except the 4th, illustrated by :

```js
this.setLastName = function(name) { 
    // When doing this while the field is empty, the "required"
    // error disappear but the input stays empty.
    this.userForm.lastName.$setViewValue(name);
    this.userForm.lastName.$validate();  
}
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, I think you are binding to the incorrect model.

`$ctrl.userForm` is your form controller instance. The "name" attribute on ngModel exposes the form control (the input) instance to the form controller instance. So, `$ctrl.userForm.lastName` is not going to be the raw model value, it'll be an object with `ngModelController` functions.

In order to pre-populate the form controller correctly, ensure the ng-model expression has the correct initial value. Currently, your `ng-model` is bound to `$scope.lastName`. That's why it's rendering empty instead of "toto." To fix it, you could add `$scope.lastName = "toto"` to your controller, but since you are avoiding `$scope` usage, just define `this.lastName = 'toto'` and use `ng-model="$ctrl.lastName"`.

From the button, you just need to do `this.lastName = name`. No need to call `$render` and `$validate` yourself because Angular does it on behalf of you because it detects a change in model value.

In case it helps, I just wrote an [article](https://medium.com/product-at-catalant-technologies/i-have-to-relearn-angulars-form-api-every-time-i-use-it-83287c521968#.oss671g01) for what's happening under the hood in `ngModelController` if you're interested.

Hope it helps!

```js
var app = angular.module('jsbin', ['ngMessages']);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function() {
  
  /**
   * Here I would like to set a defaut state form the form.
   * 
   * This object will be replaced by the FormController instance
   * as defined in the view by "<form name="$ctrl.userForm">" 
   * with no regards for its current content.
   */

  this.lastName = 'toto';
  this.formResults = {};
  
  /**
   * I would like to set the value of one or multiple fields
   * in the controller.
   * Here I try to set "lastName" with no success.
   *
   * I excepted something like:
   * this.userForm.setValues({
   *   lastName : 'Doe', 
   *   firstName: 'John'
   * });
   * 
   * or 
   *
   * this.userForm.setValue('lastName', 'value here');
   *
   * ...
   */
  this.setLastName = function(name) { 
    // When doing this while the field is empty, the "required"
    // error disappear but the input stays empty.
    this.lastName = name;
  }
  
  
  /**
   * Here a clean way to extract current values of the form would be handy..
   * Something like : 
   * this.userForm.getValues(); 
   */
  this.submit = function(form){
    this.formResults = {};
    if (form.$valid) {
      var values = {};
      angular.forEach(form, function (value, key) {
        if (typeof(value) === 'object' && value.hasOwnProperty('$modelValue')) {
            values[key] = value.$modelValue;
        } 
      });
      this.formResults = values;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="jsbin">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as $ctrl">
    
    <form name="$ctrl.userForm" novalidate>
      <label>Last Name:</label>
      <input name="lastName" ng-model="$ctrl.lastName" required="" minlength="2" type="text">
      <ng-messages for="$ctrl.userForm.lastName.$error">
          <ng-message when="minlength">Too small!</ng-message>
          <ng-message when="required">Required!</ng-message>
      </ng-messages>
      <button ng-click="$ctrl.submit($ctrl.userForm)">Submit</button>
    </form>
    
    <p>
      <button ng-click="$ctrl.setLastName('Test')">Set value to "lastName"</button>
    </p>
    
    <h2>Results</h2>
    {{$ctrl.formResults|json}}

  </div>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.9/angular-messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it seems to work as expected in the jsbin, thanks! I guess I would create a "userFormData" object holding ng-model values. However, in my real case it doesn't work because I use angular material which should add a "md-input-invalid" class when an error occurs but doesn't when the field value is changed programmatically. This was not in my original question so I consider this one resolved. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the view (input) that just changed, to render itself so the model value is changed (so the new value displays in the form field).

```
angular.element('your element id').controller('ngModel').$render()
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you it works by replacing the call to "$validate()" by "$render()" in setLastName(string). But it looks like very ugly and hacky, is there a better way to achieve this whole thing ?